# the function of "would" in a particular sentence

Tags: meaning

*In March 1933, shortly after the Nazis took power, Heidegger visited Jaspers in Heidelberg and they spent the visit amiably enough, listening to recordings of Gregorian chant and discussing philosophy. When the conversation turned, inevitably, to politics, Heidegger **would only say**, "One must get involved".*

Source. Mark Lilla: *The Reckless Mind*, p. 23.

Could you please clarify to me why "would say" is used in the above sentence. I presume that it works here to indicate past tense. But "would + verb" is used when we talk about repeated past actions. So is the meaning of the sentence that Heidegger during the debate on politcal matters just repeated many times the quoted words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, *would* is the past tense of *will*, and *will* had a meaning of "be willing to" (in fact it underlies the word "willing").

This meaning is rare in Modern English, but this idiom "would only say" is a case where it survives: it means "was willing to say ... and no more".

Comment: I note that this meaning is not confined to the past, but it is limited to negative contexts (including quasi-negative words like "only"). Sometimes forms using it are actually ambiguous: _He won't go_ can mean "He is not willing to go", but it can also be a simple prediction.

Answer (score 1):

It means either

a) that whenever the conversation turned to politics, H. said only that one must get involved, or

b) that when the conversation turned to politics, H. said that one must get involved, but when prodded to be more forthcoming than that, and asked to give a more specific opinion, he was not more forthcoming.

b) is the more likely here, given Lilla's "When the conversation turned, inevitably..."  for if he meant that the conversation always seemed to turn to politics, he would probably have used the word "returned" instead of "turned".

Comment: Thank for your reply. And would the meaning of the sentence be the same if the author would write simply: he only said…?

Comment: No, it would not be exactly the same meaning.  "he would only say" implies  some form of repetition, i.e. whenever the conversation returned to politics, or when pressed to be more forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the function of would in this particular sentence?

It is past-tense.  It is saying that Heidegger refused to say anything else.  The one comment Heidegger did agree to make was, "One must get involved".

> Would the meaning of the sentence be the same if the author would
>   write simply: he only said…?

No.  "He only said" only expresses that Heidegger didn't say anything else.  While that's true, it's not the whole truth.  It fails to indicate that he refused to say more on the matter.  "He only said" says some of what the original text meant but not all of it.